# Product Image not displaying in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a website when suddenly the product image on the single page stops displaying. But when I click on the empty space where the image supposed to be it pops up with the image. I can't seem to figure out why the sudden loss of image.

http://www.efikobooks.com/product/the-huge-kids-quiz-book/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your page under the "single-pimage" div there is an another div with class name "woocommerce-product-gallery" which has an inline css "opacity:0" that's why your product image is not displaying set it to 1 and image will appear.. or just paste this in your css...

```
.single-pimage .woocommerce-product-gallery{
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darsh, I did not see that. Why do you think that added opacity all of a sudden cause the pictures were showing previously

Comment: Darsh khakhkhar thanks mehn, I dont know how that opacity came about. The image was showing perfectly and suddenly disappeared. I dont have an idea why that happened.

Comment: @Joseph It can be added by a plugin or maybe some kind of js is responsible for it. can't say the actual reason behind it. but as it is added inline and if you  haven't made any changes into that file then there are chances that some js is responsible for that opacity.

Comment: @Joseph If the answer solved your problem then please mark it as a correct answer..